# Error setting Wordpress site in Docker container environment

Tags: wordpress, docker, apache

I would like to setup a docker environment with three container: one for mysql server bind on port 3306, one for apache/letsencrypt bind on port 80 and 443 and one for hosting some wordpress sites, bind on port 8073.

I have configured this docker-compose file and for every container there is a Dockerfile that install the rispective image:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    mysql-server:
        build: 'mysql-server'
        container_name: mysql-server
        volumes:
            - db_volumes:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
    apache-letsencrypt:
        build: 'apache-letsencrypt'
        container_name: apache-letsencrypt
        environment:
            WEBMASTER_MAIL: "example@example.it"
        volumes:
            - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
            - vhosts_volumes:/etc/apache2/sites-available
            - log_volumes:/var/log/apache2
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        network_mode: host
    wordpress_php7.2:
        build: 'php7.2'
        container_name: wordpress_php7.2
        environment:
            DB_SERVER: mysql-server
        depends_on:
            - mysql-server
        volumes:
            - /var/www/wordpress_php7.2:/var/www
            - vhosts_volumes:/etc/apache2/sites-available
            - log_volumes:/var/log/apache2
        ports:
            - "8073:80"
volumes:
    db_volumes:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            type: 'none'
            o: 'bind'
            device: '/var/www/databases'
    vhosts_volumes:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            type: 'none'
            o: 'bind'
            device: '/etc/apache2/sites-available'
    log_volumes:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            type: 'none'
            o: 'bind'
            device: '/var/log/apache2'
```

After containers creation, I put wordpress site in /var/www/wordpress_php7.2/www.example.com and setup database in mysql container.

Furthermore I create letsencrypt certificate with success in apache-letsencrypt container.
So I must set vhost and I create three vhosts for one site:
one that I put inside wordpress container bind on port 80 inside container:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.example.com
 ServerAlias example.com
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

 <Directory /var/www/example.com>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 </Directory>


 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example.com.error.log
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example.com.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

And other two vhosts inside apache-letsencrypt container bind on ports 80 and 443:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com

  ## Redirect rules
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/

  ## Server aliases
  ServerAlias example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile      "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/cert.pem"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem"
        SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem"
        SSLCACertificatePath    "/etc/ssl/certs"

        SSLProxyEngine on
        ProxyPass / http://www.example.com:8073/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com:8073/
        ProxyRequests Off
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally I pass request inside docker network and setup in apache container in /etc/hosts path this:

```
172.17.0.1 www.example.com
```

After change inside database site in wp_option table the https path of site (https://www.example.com), I receive error too_many_redirects.

I have debug and if I echo something and exit in index.php before load site, all works correctly, so I suppose that there are some processes inside code that not works.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution for wordpress site:

insert this directive inside vhosts binded on port 443:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
```

to identify the protocol that client use connecting to proxy (doc. -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto).

After that I have insert this code at first line of functions.php file of theme:

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

to avoid template redirect.

Now everything seems to be working correctly